# A way to detect empty cells in CSV and replace them with NULL in sql query

Tags: python, database, csv, mysql-python

I have a dynamic csv file with cells that start out empty but over time will get filled with values. To get this csv file into a database I convert it on the fly to sql and upload to my database, however, empty cells in the CSV file are showing up with empty values in the database but are not set to NULL. Is there a way to detect empty cells and set them to NULL before the sql is uploaded?

Here's my code:

```
import MySQLdb
import csv
import sys

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "", "point")
cur = db.cursor()
csv_data = csv.reader(open("/home/dboo/data1/data/Fiverphy/tablecells222.csv"))
header = next(csv_data)

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablecells222')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE tablecells222(
   id               INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,less_id        INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,datetime         VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
  ,status           VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
  ,less              VARCHAR(30)
  ,team1            VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
  ,team2            VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
  ,team1         INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,team2         INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,team1_code       VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
  ,team2_code       VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
  ,prob1            VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
  ,prob2            VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,prob3          VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
  ,round            VARCHAR(30)
  ,day         VARCHAR(30)
  ,score1           NUMERIC(3)
  ,score2           NUMERIC(3)
  ,adj_score1       VARCHAR(18)
  ,adj_score2       VARCHAR(18)
  ,chances1         VARCHAR(18)
  ,chances2         VARCHAR(19)
  ,moves1           VARCHAR(19)
  ,moves2           VARCHAR(19)
  ,aggregate VARCHAR(30)
  ,shootout  VARCHAR(30)
);
''')

for row in csv_data:
    print(row)
    cur.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO tablecells222(id,less_id,datetime,status,less,team1,team2,team1_id,team2_id,team1_code,team2_code,prob1,prob2,prob3,round,day,score1,score2,adj_score1,adj_score2,chances1,chances2,moves1,moves2,aggregate,shootout) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);", row)

db.commit()
cur.close()
print("Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```py
for row in csv_data: 
    if row['data_value'] == "" or row['data_value'] == " ":
        row['data_value'] == None
        # row['data_value'] == "Null"
    else:
        cur.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to always execute, even if you replace a field with None.

```
for row in csv_data: 
    if row['data_value'] == "":
        row['data_value'] == None
    cur.execute()
```